# How to pass an instance of an array to a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, parameter-passing

I have a checkbox group that I want to get all checked items. I am trying to pass an Array to a function so I can get all checked items but it's not working.

```
checkedCategory: Array<number>;


contains(checkedArr: Array<number>, id: number): boolean {
  if (checkedArr instanceof Array) {
    return checkedArr.indexOf(id) > -1;
  } else if (!!checkedArr) {
    return checkedArr === id;
  }
  return false;
}

private add(checkedArr: Array<number>, id: number) {
  if (!this.contains(checkedArr, id)) {
    console.log('add: ' + checkedArr);
    if (checkedArr instanceof Array) {
      checkedArr.push(id);
    } else {
      checkedArr = [id];
    }
  }
}

private remove(checkedArr: Array<number>, id: number) {
  const index = checkedArr.indexOf(id);
  if (!checkedArr || index < 0) {
    return;
  }
  checkedArr.splice(index, 1);
}

toggleCategory(id: number) {
  if (this.contains(this.checkedCategory, id)) {
    this.remove(this.checkedCategory, id);
  } else {
    this.add(this.checkedCategory, id);
  }
}
```

I have a (click) event in my checkbox that will call togglecategory

```
(click)="toggleCategory(category.id)"
```

Then, when I try to console.log the 'checkedCategory' it's undefined.

I have 3 checkboxes group and I want to reuse the 'contains/add/remove' function that's why I want to pass an array.

Thank you

Comment: Where does `checkedCategory` get assigned to?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Im passing it in contains ans checkedArr

Comment: Sure, but where does it *come from*? You never define it in the code you posted (which may well be why, when you try to log it, it's undefined)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Isn't it this one? checkedCategory: Array<number>; sorry im a total newbie. If that's not it. What should I do to have 3 arrays that can store selected items. I'm super confused.

Comment: That just defines its type, there's no `=` (`=`, the assignment operator, is need to assign values to variables)

Comment: @CertainPerformance woo. you're right! I tried putting in values in the checkedCategory which will be the case since items are checked by default and it worked! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `toggleCategory(20)` see what happens, in your case you will see that your function will print `add: undefined`. so the first thing you must debug is your add function. I think the issue is that your array is not defined. Try to initalize your empty array like this `let checkedCategory: Array<number> = Array();`
But either way, You need to debug your add function. Good Luck :)

If you have any questions about why this is the solution, let me know, I dont mind sharing the Theory aspect to why this occurs if you are interested.

Comment: Awesome! This one works too. I was passing it as an undefined object that's why it's not pushing new items.